# How to load .env file for different environments in python?

Tags: python, flask, dotenv

I have three .env files for local, dev and prod environment and I have to load specific environments  file while doing deployment for that server i.e If am doing DEV deployment then dev .env file should load all.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the pip module [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) to load .env files.
Here's what you need to do:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(some_path)
```

Now the vars in the env file located at `some_path` can be used with `os.getenv`

Comment: How does this answer the question? I would imagine OP has local.env, dev.env, prod.env. I think he wants to know how to specify which one to use in the code. Off the top of my head he should go with dynaconf or hydra

Comment: @Denis Expanding on Lcj's answer , that's an easy problem to solve by adding an environment variable for the filename (or path) 

`import os; env_file = os.environ['DOTENV_FILE']; load_dotenv(env_file)`

If you didn't want to use an environment variable, you could add a command-line argument or something.

Answer (score 2):

**Here is my solution how to handle loading different env files for different needs**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv

APP_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROFILE_DIR = Path(APP_ROOT) / 'profile'
STORAGE_DIR = Path(APP_ROOT) / 'storage'

# add configurations here...

FLASK_ENV = os.getenv('FLASK_ENV') or 'development'

# define here environment config files you want to load
ENVIRONMENTS = {
    'development': '.env',
    'docker': '.env.docker',
}

dotenv_path = os.path.join(APP_ROOT, ENVIRONMENTS.get(FLASK_ENV) or '.env')

# Load Environment variables
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
```